# Problem linking static library vs dynamic library

Tags: c, mpi, static-libraries

I've successfully developed a code using a dynamic library.
Nowadays I need to move to a static library.
So I've built the library with make as specified by the author but when I tried to build my program I've faced these messages:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfft3dmpi.a(remap3d_wrap.o): in function `remap3d_create':
/home/mirco/Scrivania/fftmpi-1Oct18/src/remap3d_wrap.cpp:36: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfft3dmpi.a(remap3d_wrap.o): in function `remap3d_create_fortran(int, void**)':
/home/mirco/Scrivania/fftmpi-1Oct18/src/remap3d_wrap.cpp:45: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
```

And so on..
I've tried to specify, in the makefile, the full path of the library or to use `-l(name of the library)` but I still face the same messages

My makefile is

```
$(CC) -O3 -o exe channel_mpi.o initialization.o convol_trasp.o fft_support.o data_man.o dnsdata.o dnsdirect.o /home/mirco/Scrivania/fftmpi-1Oct18/src/libfft3dmpi.a -lm
```

The compiler is h5pcc, which is mpicc wrapped with some flags to use HDF5 library.

Have I done mistakes??

Thanks for your help

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can probably add that as the answer since it is very likely the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you very much!! You were right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`operator new` is a C++ thing. It seems you're building with C++ code and not C. The makefile variable `$(CC)` is the C compiler, `$(CXX)` is the C++ compiler.

So the solution is to switch the compiler you're using for linking.

---

When linking the C++ frontend program (typically `g++` on Linux systems) will automatically add the C++ standard library. It's this library that contains the default implementations of many C++ standard functions, like the functions needed for the C++ `new` operator.

It is possible to use the C frontend (`gcc`) as well, but then you have to explicitly link with the C++ library. For `gcc` that means you have to add `-lstdc++`.